# application function using index small if in order to find more than one matching result

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub IndMat()
Dim wh1 As Worksheet
Dim wh2 As Worksheet
Set wh1 = Sheets("DATA")
Set wh2 = Sheets("Dashboard")
Dim y As Variant
Dim x As Long
Dim lr1 As Long
Dim lr2 As Long
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim i As Integer
‘This is the formula I want to use but in an application function ‘”=IFERROR    (INDEX(DATA!$B$2:$B$257;SMALL(IF(DATA! $D$2:$D$257=DATAMATCH!$M$7;ROW(DATA!$D$2:$D$257)-MIN(ROW(DATA!$D$2:$D$257))   +1);ROWS($B$13:$I15)));"")”
 Lr1 = wh1.Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row
  Lr2 = wh2.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

Set rng1 = wh1.Range("D2:D" & lr1)
Set rng2 = wh2.Range("A2:A" & lr1)
For i = 2 To lr2
 wh2.Cells(i, 13) = Application.Index(rng2, Application.Small(Application.if  (rng1 = wh2.Cells(12, 1), Application.Row(rng1), Application.Min(Application.Row(rng1)) + 1), Application.Rows("B13")), "")
Next
End Sub
```

Kind of newbie using application function so would be very pleased if someone could help me translate this function to application function..

Comment: What you are looking for is `Application.WorksheetFunction`.  You can use `WorksheetFunction` for short.  This is for worksheet commands like `Index, Small, etc`.  You do not need that for `Rows`.

Comment: Do you mean it's to complex for using application function like application.index etc. or? I have used this kind of setup when using index match which retrieves only one match. That worked well, however this is a little more complex

Comment: Not too complex, just informing you on the usage.  Are you sure the formula you want to convert works?  At one point you are testing whether a range equals the result of a formula.  I don't think that will work.

Comment: The formula works, tested it before I wrote it in a VBA enviroment.

Comment: Ok, so what iI did was the second best solution.  Used this "Selection.FormulaArray = _  "myformula"" . And then hide the formulas by a second script. However if there's anyone that have a solution for the application.formula mentioned above I would be glad to learn that. Thnaks everyone!